# Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, sql-server-2012

this is my application .properties file

```
server.context-path=/moneymonster
management.security.enabled=false

#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/money_monster?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=projej30521
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

#Jpa
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

#batch
spring.batch.job.enabled=false

#security.user.password=password

#jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

the application.propeties file consist of configuration of hibernate and jpa and sql server 12 configuration

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.datasource.username= "you must set username"
```

if you have password you must set it

and this example

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Projects@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i will make sure to check that and come back to you with an update or an issue

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any username/password for logging in to the db in your properties file.

You can make a new user and it's password and create the corresponding db in your local machine if not exists.

For creating new user, login as root credential to mysql and type:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

replace the newuser and password accordingly.

Don't forget to grant privilege to the user, given you want to give this user all privileges on that specific database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname . * TO 'newuser';
```

Add the username and the password in your application.properties file.
Or, if you have username and password, then just edit the properties file accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the answer i will make sure to check that and come back to you with an update

Comment: @AmanRSingh,  if it answers your query, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.